# Android: Image received over socket is corrupted

Tags: android, sockets, file-transfer

Hi here's the problem: the server sends the image to the client correctly ( I think ). The file received from the client is the same size of the file present on the server phone, so every byte got transferred I guess but still the image is not visible. Either the server and the client are android phones. Thanks in advance I hope you can help me.

Server code:

```
public class FileActivity extends Activity {

private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;

private byte [] mybytearray;

private String tmp = null;

private TextView tv;

private File myFile;

private int l;

private String path;

private EditText editText;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private Socket client;

public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

private final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private byte [] imgbyte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread sThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    sThread.start();
}

public void sendListener(View v) {

    tmp = editText.getText().toString();

    path = "/sdcard/" + tmp;

    myFile = new File(path);Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");           

    l = (int) myFile.length();Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

    tv.setText(path + "  " + Integer.toString(l));  

    tmp = Integer.toString(l);  Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

    String test = tmp;



    //out.println(tmp);
    Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
    try {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println(test);
        //out.close();
        Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024]; //create a byte array to file
        Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
         bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);  
         Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");


         Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
         try{
             outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
         } catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.d("OUTPUT", "UFFFF");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        /* Log.d("SERVER", "ALMOST");
         outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); Log.d("SERVER", "DONE");//write file to the output stream byte by byte*/
      //  outputStream.flush();
       // outputStream.close();

         Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
         int count = 0;
         int size = 0;

         while((count = bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0 , mybytearray.length)) != -1)
         {
            // count = bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0 , mybytearray.length);
             size += count;
             Log.d("SERVER", "SEND");
             try{
                 outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(count));
         }
         Log.d("SERVER", "DONE");
         bufferedInputStream.close();
         outputStream.close();
               client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }   


}


public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            //outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

            Log.d("SERVER", "Connesso");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TEST", "UFFFAAA");
        }           
    }

}

private String getLocalIpAddress() {

    String tmp = "";

    int i = 0;

    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) 
                { 

                    tmp += "IP: " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n"; 

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return tmp;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Client code:

```
public class FileActivity extends Activity {

private EditText serverIp, getPort;
private Button connectPhones;
private TextView tv, tvIP;

private Boolean connected = false;

private String serverIpAddress, portStr;

private Socket socket;

private int port, len;

private String filepath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);

    tvIP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IPtv);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Portatv);
    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    getPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_port); 
}

public void connectListener(View v)
{
    if (!connected) {
        serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
        portStr = getPort.getText().toString();
        if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
            Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
            cThread.start();
        }
    }
}

public class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        port = Integer.parseInt(portStr);

        socket = new Socket();

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connessione in corso...");
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connesso!");
            connected = true;

            DataInputStream dis;
            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                int bytes;
                byte[] b = new byte[32];
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String l = in.readLine();
                //String line = Integer.toString(l);
                Log.d("PROVA", l);  
                try
                {
                    len = Integer.parseInt(l); Log.d("CLIENT", Integer.toString(len));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] img = new byte[1082922];  //1082922
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/img.jpg");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                /*bytes = dis.read(img, 0, img.length);

                bos.write(img, 0, img.length);*/
                int count = 0;
                while ((bytes = dis.read(img)) != -1) {
                    count += bytes;
                    Log.d("CLIENT", Integer.toString(count));
                    Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(bytes));
                    //Write to file
                    bos.write(img, 0, bytes);
                }
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                Log.d("TCP", "Save to file");
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Errore", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }

}

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(connected == true)
        {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Within _sendListener_ on server side - you read first 1024 bytes from _bufferedInputStream_ - never storing them anywhere - before you start actual read/write loop.

Comment: You're actually right, I so didn't notice it! Thank you! Now the server sends all the bytes! Sadly on the client side the image is corrupted, not visible at all.. Can you help me further? Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're combining buffered and unbuffered I/O on the same underlying streams. The buffered reader will steal data from the other stream by filling its buffer with whatever is available. You have data input and output streams: use them for everything. You can send the file size via writeInt()/readInt().

Comment: So this is why the image received is corrupted?

Comment: Of course it is. Missig data -= corruption, wouldn't you say?

Answer (score -1):

You have already one `.read()` before the `while` loop. And those bytes you do not `write()` so the client does not receive the first bytes of the file. O i see now that you write them but do not count them in size. Anyhow: bad construction. And for the first read you should have used a count variable too. And write only count bytes. Better remove the first read completely.

Comment: So no errors? And any idea why the server does not send all the bytes?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Please reread carefully what i wrote.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean. The first "read()" is to get the file size and the second "read()" is to get the file itself.

Comment: Ohhh sorry is that the idea. Good idea to send the file size first. But please explain how the size is send. And on the server side you first reserve 32 bytes after which you read a line. And you do not parse a value out of it. Instead you use a fixed buffer. I cannot follow your code. Please explain.

Comment: Had a better look at your server code where the file content is send. You are not determining the file size there and you arent sending either a file size or a line before sending the content. I saw also that the client tries to get an integer value from the line read.