# Android socket does not receive all the bytes of an image

Tags: android, sockets

Hi I'm having problem receiving an image
In the last while it simply doesn't receive all the bytes and the program does not exit the while condition. With a 77970 bytes image, this receives 61592 bytes then just does nothing. It keeps stuck in the while. I dunno what to do, thanks for any help.

public class FileActivity extends Activity {

```
private EditText serverIp, getPort, exT;
private Button connectPhones;
private TextView tv, tvIP;

private Boolean connected = false;

private String serverIpAddress, portStr,ex;

private Socket socket;

private int port, len;

private String filepath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);

    exT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tvIP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IPtv);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Portatv);
    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    getPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_port); 
}

public void connectListener(View v)
{
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
    connectPhones.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    getPort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    serverIp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    tvIP.setTextSize(16f);
    tvIP.setText("Connesso");

    exT.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    ex = exT.getText().toString();

    if (!connected) {
        serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
        portStr = getPort.getText().toString();
        if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
            Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
            cThread.start();
        }
    }
}

public class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        port = Integer.parseInt(portStr);

        socket = new Socket();

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connessione in corso...");
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);                
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connesso!");
            connected = true;



            DataInputStream dis;
            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                int bytes;
                byte[] b = new byte[32];
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String l = in.readLine();
                //String line = Integer.toString(l);
                Log.d("PROVA", l);  
                try
                {
                    len = Integer.parseInt(l); Log.d("CLIENT", Integer.toString(len));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] img = new byte[1024];  //1082922
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/" + ex);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                /*bytes = dis.read(img, 0, img.length);

                bos.write(img, 0, img.length);*/
                int count = 0;
                while ((bytes = dis.read(img)) != -1) {
                    count += bytes;
                    Log.d("CLIENT", Integer.toString(count));
                    Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(bytes));
                    //Write to file
                    bos.write(img, 0, bytes);
                }
                //bos.flush();
                //bos.close();
                Log.d("TCP", "Save to file");
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Errore", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }

}

 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(connected == true)
        {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Server:

```
public class FileActivity extends Activity {

private String test;

private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
private OutputStream outputStream;

private byte [] mybytearray;

private String tmp = null;

private TextView tv;

private File myFile;

private int l;

private String path;

private EditText editText;

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

private Socket client;

public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

private final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private byte [] imgbyte;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread sThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    sThread.start();
}

public void sendListener(View v) {

    tmp = editText.getText().toString();

    path = "/sdcard/" + tmp;

    myFile = new File(path);Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

    if(myFile.exists())
    {
        l = (int) myFile.length();Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

        tv.setText(path + "  Size:" + Integer.toString(l)); 

        tmp = Integer.toString(l);  Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

        test = tmp;

        Thread t = new Thread(new sSend());
         t.start();
    }
    else
    {
        tv.setText("Il file non esiste");
    }


}

public class sSend implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())), true);
            out.println(test);
            //out.close();
            Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024]; //create a byte array to file
            Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
             bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);  
             Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");

             //bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length); //read the file
             Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
             try{
                 outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
             } catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.d("OUTPUT", "UFFFF");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

            Log.d("SERVER", "WORKS");
             int count = 0;
             int size = 0;

             while((count = bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0 , mybytearray.length)) != -1)
             {
                // count = bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0 , mybytearray.length);
                 size += count;
                 Log.d("SERVER", "SEND");
                 try{
                     outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(count));
             }
             Log.d("SERVER", "DONE");
             Log.d("SERVER", Integer.toString(size));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            //outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

            Log.d("SERVER", "Connesso");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TEST", "UFFFAAA");
        }           
    }

}

private String getLocalIpAddress() {

    String tmp = "";

    int i = 0;

    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) 
                { 

                    tmp += "IP: " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n"; 

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return tmp;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: When you say its "stuck in the while" what do you mean? Is it blocking on `read`? Or somewhere else? Why have you elected to use a `DataInputStream` instead of the `BufferedReader`?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, and yes it is blocking on read. Actually I thought that was the way to retrieve data, I'm new on Android programming, should I use a BufferedReader?

Comment: Does it always stop at 61592 bytes? What happens with a different file? My hunch is that the way you handle the input & output streams isn't cooperating.

Comment: Same thing with different file. And yes mostly it stops at 61592, it rarely change, do you want me to post the server code? And thank you so much for helping me, I'd so need this ready by tonight

Comment: Posting the server portion might be helpful. If the `read` call blocks it means its waiting on more data or an `EOS (End of Stream) Signal.

Comment: I posted the server code, you have no idea how grateful I am. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: The code at a glance looks correct except you never close your output stream on the server. Its hard to say without testing but I think you'll benefit from using Buffered streams or Stream Writer objects like `PrintWriter` and `BufferedReader` instead of what you're using now. They help negotiate the flow of bytes which could be causing your issue.

Comment: Mmm the fact is if I use this android server with a C# client on the computer, the client gets the images correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a repost. Why did you start a new thread? The other one was not ready yet. We had discovered some problems and you do not even mention them here. OP tries to send file size first and then the content. Also the client should read the file size first but it is a complete mess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418656/android-image-received-over-socket-is-corrupted/24419269#comment37787748_24419269

Comment: What is a mess? The client reads the file size successfully, the problem is: it does not read all the bytes the server sends